# Reading large csv file data data from Azure blob storage fails after 15 minutes

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

I have created a c# Azure Webjob console app, this app reads csv file from Azure storage and for each record in the csv it performs some actions.
the csv file contains around 6000 records, the job fails after 15 minutes and I get the following error:

My code:

```
var blobConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure_blob_connection"];
//string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(blobConnectionString);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("resetaccountlist");

BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("testaccount.CSV");
#endregion
if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
{
    var response = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Value.Content))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            if(line!=null || line != "")
            {
                UserService.ResetPassword(line);
            }
        }

    
    }
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("---Blob file does not exist---");
}
```

here is the error I get:

```
  (Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveAsync(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadAsync(Memory`1 destination)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadAsync(Memory`1 destination)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpBaseStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ReadTimeoutStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ReadTimeoutStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetriableStream.RetriableStreamImpl.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.NonDisposingStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBufferAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsyncInternal()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsyncInternal()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsync()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Dev\RioCan\ReGeneratePassword\Program.cs:line 32
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ] 
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.DownloadStreamingInternal(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, IProgress`1 progressHandler, String operationName, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartDownloadAsync(HttpRange range, BlobRequestConditions conditions, Boolean rangeGetContentHash, Int64 startOffset, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.DownloadAsync(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable`1 timeout, String range, String leaseId, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentMD5, Nullable`1 rangeGetContentCRC64, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, Nullable`1 encryptionAlgorithm, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:38 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.<ProcessAsync>g__ProcessAsyncInner|4_0(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext(Thread threadPoolThread)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.MoveNext()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(IAsyncStateMachineBox box, Boolean allowInlining)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetExistingTaskResult(Task`1 task, TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetResult(TResult result)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
[06/15/2022 17:51:39 > 152619: ERR ]    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.AsyncStateMachineBox`1.ExecutionContextCallback(Object s)
```

Comment: Have you considered pulling the whole file and then processing it? 6000 records is not that big. And if there is no shared state preventing it, you might even be able to do batches of lines in parallel.

Comment: I put the other part of my code, could you suggest what I am missing ?